# Why are we allowed to add slack or surplus variables in linear programming?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

It may sound like a silly question, but I just realized that I can do the simplex algorithm, yet I can't answer that question. When we introduce slack or surplus variables, why don't we 'undo' that step at the end? Why does their presence not change the answer?

Answer (score 3):

A slack variable does not change the problem, just its representation. If you have a constraint $$ f(x) \le b$$ with $x$ variables and $b$ a constant, then you replace it with $$ f(x)+ \lambda=b$$ and $$ \lambda \ge 0$$ which amounts to the same thing. $\lambda$ is a new variable called a slack variable (cause it "picks up the slack" of the original inequality).

Thus introducing slack variables just gives you a different representation of the same problem. There's no reason to "get rid of" them... they're essential in the new representation.

At the end of the day you have your optimum $(x,\lambda).$ $x$ is your optimum answer and then the value for $\lambda$ just tells you how much room that constraint still has at the optimum $x$... if it is saturated to $\lambda = 0$ that means the constraint binds.

Comment: Ah that last line really brings it together for me. Thanks

Comment: A question about simplex. We start at a vertex and move to another vertex only and if it is less optimal we stop. But is it possible that if we had moved beyond that we would have gotten something better than the original solution? On a 2d plane imagine a hexagon with 6 vertices and I am between vertex 1 and 3, at 2, but the optimal solution is at 4? If that makes any sense.

Comment: @anna_xox Great question. It's not obvious at first that you would achieve anything but a local optimum with this kind of search. However it turns out that if a vertex is suboptimal, it will always have at least one direction to travel in that increases the objective. The keyword here is 'convexity', but you should be able to make sense of it  on a simple 2D example. Draw a feasible zone and then draw level sets for your objective (parallel lines). You should be able to discern that (a) the maximum happens at a vertex (b) any local maximum amongst the vertices is a global maximum.